# can not set double field to null value JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jakarta-ee, repository

```
@Column(name="NU_MAGASIN")
private short nuMagasin;
```

i create entities from table and this column in my db got null value but the didn;t accept it 
and i got this message

Can not set short field supplycam.entities.Nomenclature.nuMagasin to null value

Comment: The message pretty much says it all - a Java short primitive is not nullable. If you want to have a nullable field representing a short, use the Java's `Short` wrapper.

Comment: @Smutje Please don't answer questions in comments and add your comment as answer. I'm tired of looking at already answered questions. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

To have an answer on this question I add the code how it must look like:

```
@Column(name="NU_MAGASIN")
private Short nuMagasin;
```

In Java short, int, long, float, double, byte, char, boolean are primitive types and not nullable. But there exists a wrapper type for each of these. Usually starting with a capital letter.